# Redirect from a page URL to another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, redirect

Basically, a colleague has sent out a poster with a web address on it as example.com/pagename, however, when we create a page on our website it automatically creates the URL as

```
  example.com/view/pagename
```

Is there a way that I can redirect the URL he has put on the poster to go to the actual URL of the webpage? Not sure if there's something I can put on the server or if I do this through our host (1and1).

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: CAn you give more detail about the framework you are using?

Comment: I suppose you could remove `pagename` file from the view folder..

Answer (score 1):

A simple and fast solution is to create a foler `pagename` on your document root and add a **index.html** file in this folder with this in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/view/pagename" />
```

You can also add a JavaScript redirect and a link with the right URL for the redirect so if a browser doesn't support JS or HTML redirects the user can always use the direct link.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/view/pagename" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "http://example.com/view/pagename";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        If you are not redirected automatically, follow the <a href="http://example.com/view/pagename">link to pagename</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this very easily by adding a .htaccess rule, assuming you are using apache as your web server.

> .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /pagename /view/pagename
```

Comment: we use 1and1 for our web hosting, I'm not sure how to do that with them, they seem to have an option to forward the whole domain to another url but not just one specific page

Comment: you would upload a file called .htaccess to your webroot, or if the file already exists, you would edit it and add the line to it.

Answer (score 1):

In that page you can user the header function in PHP.

so in page example.com/page1.php, use like

header("location: example.com/page2.php");

so when page1 loads it will automatically redirect to page2